# Is there a way to adjust a picture automatically to the screen in kivy?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I've watched some kivy tutorials and they all say that labels, button, etc, will be adjusted if the screen changes. But my image doesn't. Then I found out that it's because I gave it a specific location. So I use root.width and root.height instead but it's still doesn't scale up.
Here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class main(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        root = Widget()
        self.search = TextInput(multiline = False, pos = (250, 325), size = (self.width * 3, self.height/2))
        self.add_widget(self.search)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Rectangle(source = 'foundit.png', pos = root.center, size = (root.width*4, root.height*4))



class found_it(App):
    def build(self):
        return main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    found_it().run()
```

Thanks in advance feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `size` using `root.width` and `root.height` in python, the `size` is set using the current values of `root.width` and `root.height` at the time that code is executed. You can write code to update that `Rectangle` whenever the `size` or `pos` of `main` changes by binding an update method to the `pos` and `size` properties of `main`.

An easier approach is to define the `Rectangle` in `kv`, like this:

```
<main>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'foundit.png'
            pos: root.center
            size: (root.width*4, root.height*4)
```

Now changes to `main` will automatically be reflected by the `Rectangle`, because the `kv` language sets up the bindings that you would otherwise have to do. You can do something similar with the `TextInput`.